# ipywidgets button: how to set a global variable in a running script?

Tags: python, user-interface, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, python-multithreading

I would like to use ipywidgets buttons to make my script interactive. But I think there's something very fundamental about GUIs and threading that I'm missing: **It seems the functions triggered by the button are only called when the main script finishes!**

The way I would like to implement this GUI is that there's my main loop that executes some calculations and checks the parameters set by the GUI on every iteration.

Let's look at this example where we have a switch button that should then change whether the main loop is executing one or the other calculation:

**Not working example**

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
import threading, time

SWITCH = False
def onclick_switch(b):
    global SWITCH
    SWITCH = not SWITCH # toggle
    print('Button clicked! Switch: %s'%(SWITCH))

# set up GUI
button = widgets.Button( description='Switch')
button.on_click( onclick_switch )
display(button)

while True:
    if SWITCH:
        res = 2*2 # do sophisticated calculations / plots etc
        print('result: %s'%(res))
    else:
        res = 3*3 # do sophisticated calculations / plots etc
        print('result: %s'%(res))
    time.sleep(1)
```

This displays the button "Switch" as expected, and prints the result of the second calculation ("result: 9") every second. However, the switch has no effect. Only after interrupting the Kernel are button clicks evaluated!

So I thought how about putting the main function in a separate thread such that it doesn't interfere with the button?

**Nearly working example**

```
SWITCH = False
def onclick_switch(b):
    global SWITCH
    SWITCH = not SWITCH # toggle
    print('Button clicked! Switch: %s'%(SWITCH))

# set up GUI
button = widgets.Button( description='Switch')
button.on_click( onclick_switch )
display(button)

def mainloop(): # loop is now a function
    while True:
        if SWITCH:
            res = 2*2 # do sophisticated calculations / plots etc
            print('result: %s'%(res))
        else:
            res = 3*3 # do sophisticated calculations / plots etc
            print('result: %s'%(res))
        time.sleep(1)

mainthread = threading.Thread( target = mainloop ) # let's use threading
mainthread.start()
```

This is closer to what I want: But it executes only once (prints "result: 9" once), and only continues after pressing the button for the first time.

I have trouble understanding this behaviour. I do understand however that it's something general for GUIs, because it's the same if I use mpl_connect (and maybe also qt / tkinter?)

In the ipywidgets examples that I found, there's no main loop, there's always just one single execution of a plotting function or so whenever the user changes anything. This is not what I need in my case, I need a main loop!

**So how should this be done in general? How do the buttons work internally so that they're not able to execute if the main loop is running? Where did I get wrong about multithreading / GUIs?**

I'm using ipywidgets 7.1.1 and jupyter 5.4.0 with python 2.7